# Запись данных по циклу в Django/Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

У меня есть некая переменная которая выводит информацию в виде **dict**:

```
[{'STAGE_ID': 'One',
  'TITLE': 'title #1', 
  'COMPANY_TITLE': 'Company #1', 
  'OPPORTUNITY': '3223.00', 
  'COMMENTS': 'comment #1'}, 

 {'STAGE_ID': 'Two', 
  'TITLE': 'title #2',  
  'COMPANY_TITLE': 'Company #2', 
  'OPPORTUNITY': '34522.11', 
  'COMMENTS': 'comment #2'}
...
...
]
```

Полученный список я хочу сохранить в БД. Для этого прохожусь по циклу и сразу пытаюсь создать запись:

```
i = 0
for i in deals[i]:
    DealsList.objects.create(
        Stage_id=deals[i]['STAGE_ID'],
        Title=deals[i]['TITLE'],
        Opportunity=deals[i]['OPPORTUNITY'],
        Comments=deals[i]['COMMENTS'],
        Country=deals[i]['COMMENTS'],
        Date=deals[i]['DATE']
    )
```

Но в итоге получаю ошибку:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for deal in deals:
    DealsList.objects.create(
        Stage_id=deal['STAGE_ID'],
        Title=deal['TITLE'],
        ...
    )
```

Если ключи в словарях точно совпадают с полями модели, то можно проще

```
for deal in deals:
    DealsList.objects.create(**deal)
```

или даже так

```
DealsList.objects.bulk_create([DealsList(**d) for d in deals])
```

для создания всех записей одним запросом.

**P.S.** Класс модели принято называть в единственном числе - `Deal` в вашем случае, а поля в нижнем регистре.

Comment: Возможно стоит добавить вариант с bulk_create.

Comment: @avtomato это отличная идея! Момент.